# Two sum for the same column and two different where conditions with group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sum

My query for getting a consolidated trial balance with two different period one as opening balance and the other one for the current period.

I have a table called JDT1 as following:

[image: JDT1 Table]

I want to get the account and total sum of Debit and credit with two different where condition related to opening balance and current balance. My query is

```
Select Account, ProfitCode, FormatCode, Acctname, (Select sum(Debit) as  
OBDebit From JDT1 Where RefDate < {?From}),  (Select sum(Credit) as 
OBCredit From JDT1 Where RefDate < {?From}), (Select sum(Debit) as OBDebit 
From JDT1 Where RefDate >= {?From} and Refdate <= {?To}),  
(Select sum(Credit) as OBCredit From JDT1 Where RefDate >= {?From} 
 and  Refdate <= {?To}) From JDT1 Full outer join [OACT] on [JDT1].[Account]
= [OACT].[AcctCode] Full outer join [OPRC] on [JDT1].[ProfitCode] =
  [OPRC].[PrcCode] Group by Account, ProfitCode
```

But unfortunately the sum is coming into one amount like group by not effecting.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour], especially [ask].Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: Please explain what a "consolidated trial balance" is and how to calculate it for different periods.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few issues.

1. When grouping, any item in the select list has to be in the group by clause.
2. You need to filter the sums to match the group by.

> ```
> SELECT Account
>       ,ProfitCode
>       ,FormatCode
>       ,Acctname
>       ,(
>           SELECT sum(Debit) AS OBDebit
>           FROM JDT1 AS t
>           WHERE RefDate < {?From}
>               AND JDT1.Account = t.Account
>               AND JDT1.ProfitCode = t.ProfitCode
>           )
>       ,(
>           SELECT sum(Credit) AS OBCredit
>           FROM JDT1 AS t
>           WHERE RefDate < {?From}
>               AND JDT1.Account = t.Account
>               AND JDT1.ProfitCode = t.ProfitCode
>           )
>       ,(
>           SELECT sum(Debit) AS OBDebit
>           FROM JDT1 AS t
>           WHERE RefDate >= {?From}
>               AND Refdate <= {?To}
>               AND JDT1.Account = t.Account
>               AND JDT1.ProfitCode = t.ProfitCode
>           )
>       ,(
>           SELECT sum(Credit) AS OBCredit
>           FROM JDT1 AS t
>           WHERE RefDate >= {?From}
>               AND Refdate <= {?To}
>               AND JDT1.Account = t.Account
>               AND JDT1.ProfitCode = t.ProfitCode
>           )
>     FROM JDT1
>      JOIN [OACT] ON [JDT1].[Account] = [OACT].[AcctCode]
>      JOIN [OPRC] ON [JDT1].[ProfitCode] = [OPRC].[PrcCode]
>     GROUP BY Account, ProfitCode, FormatCode ,Acctname
> ```